# Can I have a Laravel Model without a database table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to have a Laravel Model with all of the features and functions of a Laravel Model, but the data for the model is completely static and will never change.  I could create a database table for it, but that leaves the possibility of someone modifying the table directly.

For example:

```
    //  Model Data for Log Levels
    name      | icon                | color
    -------------------------------------------
    Emergency | fas fa-ambulance    | red
    Alert     | fas fa-bullhorn     | yellow
    Critical  | fas fa-heartbeast   | orange
    ....
```

This would be the data, stored in the model file the same as if it was a DB table, but can never be changed.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **Sushi** for that.

Eloquent's missing "array" driver.

Sometimes you want to use Eloquent, but without dealing with a database.

```
class State extends Model
{
    use \Sushi\Sushi;

    protected $rows = [
        [
            'name' => 'Emergency',
            'icon' => 'fas fa-ambulance',
            'color' => 'red'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Alert',
            'icon' => 'fas fa-bullhorn',
            'color' => 'yellow'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Critical',
            'icon' => 'fas fa-heartbeast',
            'color' => 'orange'
        ],
    ];
}
```

https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi

Comment: Note that the claim "without dealing with a database" is false. Sushi requires a SQLite database.

Answer (score -4):

I think you can use a simple model, without creating forms for injecting data, and a seeder to inculde your data at first time (when you run migrate).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since this will still create a DB table.